# [Hyperledger Fabric][Kotlin] Passing client request parameters as ByteArray to chaincode

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, hyperledger-fabric

I've been recently working with Hyperledger Fabric using kotlin as a development language. I have the local test network fully working and after some time i have pretty good understanding on how everything works. However, im still stuck passing arguments to the chaincode as Strings because every time i try to pass objects as ByteArrays it implodes somehow along the way before it reaches my chaincode method. Here is a sample of the client sending the data and the chaincode entrypoint:

Client

```
    val tl = MyClass()
    tl.machineKey = "machineHashKey"
    val path = File("/var/cenas.txt")
    tl.loadFileFromPath(path.toPath())
   
    try {
        contract!!.submitTransaction(
            "testLimitSet", tl.toByteArray()
        )
    }catch (e: Exception){
        printException(e)
    }finally {
        println("*** Transaction completed")
    }
```

ChainCode:

```
@Transaction(intent = Transaction.TYPE.SUBMIT)
fun testLimitSet(ctx: Context, testLimit: ByteArray){
    println("Here 1!")
    val id = IdentityChecks.checkIdentity(ctx)
    println("Here 2!")
    val x509 = id.second
    println("Here 3!")
}
```

MyClass simply contains 2 text fields and 1 byteArray.
I've already managed to serialize it and deserialize it locally.

The log on the chaincode machine is the following:

```
Thread[fabric-txinvoke:3,5,main] 16:39:28:613 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter processRequest                    Got routing:testLimitSet:pt.fraunhofer.newgen.chaincode.NewGenMainContract
Thread[fabric-txinvoke:3,5,main] 16:39:28:625 SEVERE  org.hyperledger.fabric.Logger error                                              A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:507)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:109)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:162)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.execution.JSONTransactionSerializer.convert(JSONTransactionSerializer.java:267)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.execution.JSONTransactionSerializer.fromBuffer(JSONTransactionSerializer.java:165)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.execution.impl.ContractExecutionService.convertArgs(ContractExecutionService.java:99)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.execution.impl.ContractExecutionService.executeRequest(ContractExecutionService.java:57)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter.processRequest(ContractRouter.java:123)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter.invoke(ContractRouter.java:134)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeInvocationTask.call(ChaincodeInvocationTask.java:106)
at org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InvocationTaskManager.lambda$newTask$17(InvocationTaskManager.java:265)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I think im most likely using the ByteArray arguments improperly. But i haven't found any chaincode examples in java/kotlin receiving data as ByteArrays.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When using the contract api in your chaincode implementation it uses JSON as the serialisation mechanism and thus expects information sent from the client to be in stringified JSON format.

The client sdks don't do this for you as for example you can write chaincode without the contract api and define your own serialiation mechanism.

With the line

```
        contract!!.submitTransaction(
            "testLimitSet", tl.toByteArray()
        )
```

you are sending an array of bytes as the string which won't mean anything to a JSON Parser. You need to convert `tl.toByteArray()` into a stringified JSON representation of that data, for example a stringified JSON representation of an array with bytes 01,02,03 might look like
'["\u0001","\u0002","\u0003"]'

However I am not really familiar with the java chaincode libraries so whether this will actually work I don't know given that the JSON representation allows for values larger that bytes and that may cause the contract api to deserialize the JSON into something that isn't type compatible with what you declare on your chaincode ie `testLimit: ByteArray` you may need to change the type or perhaps send the binary data in a different manner, for example encode it as a base64 string then send a string instead

Comment: Thank you David. I understand that. However, since the SDK allows for a submitTransaction method with a ByteArray type i thought it would make sense to allow me to send directly a ByteArray. There are 3 submitTransaction methods( 1 - byte[] submitTransaction(String name, byte[]... args) and 2 - byte[] submitTransaction(String name, String[]... args). However i've followed your sugestion and re-implemented this in a way that it uses the byteArray as with a String representation

Comment: The client SDK is not the issue here, it's the fact you are using the contract api and it by default assumes the client will send JSON. If you didn't use the contract api then you can handle the serialisation/deserialisation yourself and use the client to send it in any format you choose. however all the examples I guess only show how to use the contract api and I don't know if it's possible in the java chaincode to replace the serializer used. I'm not familiar with the java chaincode implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the problem by creating a string representation of the ByteArray. It is not the solution i originally wanted, but it works well nevertheless. I still find it strange to the SDK to provide this method:

```
byte[] submitTransaction(String name, byte[]... args)
```

and im not able to use it because it doesn't reach the chaincode endpoint with the problem described above.
My solution uses this instead:

```
byte[] submitTransaction(String name, String[]... args)
```

Here is my current solution:

```
val tl = MyClass()
tl.machineKey = "machineHashKey"
val path = File("/var/cenas.txt")
tl.loadFileFromPath(path.toPath())
   
try {
    val payload = tl.toByteArrayString()
    contract!!.submitTransaction(
        "testLimitSet", payload
    )
}catch (e: Exception){
    printException(e)
}finally {
    println("*** Transaction completed")
}
```

Where:

```
fun toByteArrayString(): String {
    return toHexString(this.toByteArray())
}

// String <- Hex(ByteArray)
fun toHexString(ba: ByteArray): String {
    return BaseEncoding.base16().encode(ba)
}

// String -> Hex(ByteArray)
fun toByteArray(s: String): ByteArray {
    return BaseEncoding.base16().decode(s)
}
```

Note that this is using

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding
```

but there are multiple implementations that can be used for this

Comment: Everything sent across the wire from the client SDK is actually sent as a byte array. The submitTransaction() overloads that allow you to supply string arguments are just a convenience and convert those strings into UTF-8 encoded byte arrays. The issue is how that byte data is being handled at the chaincode end. As mentioned in another answer, the contract API will try to coerce the raw byte data into the parameter type specified for the transaction function, but the default deserialization assumes JSON-encoded content. It doesn't know how to map to a Kotlin ByteArray